# Screen resolution changes when a key is pressed

Tags: unity, 13.04, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

Ubuntu 13.4 64 Bit (same behaviour on 12.4).

1. Laptop is off.
2. An external screen is connected via VGA.
3. I start the laptop (auto-login).
4. Screen resolution is the highest for both the laptop screen and the external screen (that's exactly what I want).
5. I press any key.
6. Resolution changes to mirrored screens.

This happens only once per running (but sometimes after standby).

How to disable the resolution change after pressing a key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is "fixed" after reinstalling Ubuntu (I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 now). It might've been caused because my PC was upgraded all the way up from Ubuntu 10.4 to 13.4.